# Optimizing Rails Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

is there anyway else to optimize this query?

It takes about 44ms to run but would love for it to be much lower. Any ideas??

```
@@accepted_list = History.select('DISTINCT ON (item_id) *')
.joins("LEFT JOIN case_statuses on histories.item_id = case_statuses.id LEFT JOIN loan_applications on loan_applications.id = case_statuses.loan_application_id")
.where("loan_applications.product_id = ?", 9)
.where(item_type: 'CaseStatus', field: 'loan_case_id', new_value: "6")
.where("histories.created_at >= ? and histories.created_at <= ?", '2017-02-10 16:00:00.000000', '2017-03-17 15:59:59.000000')
.order("item_id, histories.created_at asc")

@@accepted_cases_list.where("histories.created_at >= ? and histories.created_at <= ?", '2017-03-11 16:00:00.000000', '2017-03-17 15:59:59.000000')
.order("item_id, histories.created_at asc")
```

The only difference between the two queries are the dates and this is because, i use the records gotten from the first query and filter by more specific date ranges in the 2nd query.

But both run for about the same time as well.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Nice query you have here. What about indexes on specific columns for Histories table, do you have them ? Here is an [article about the subject](http://www.rakeroutes.com/blog/increase-rails-performance-with-database-indexes/).

Comment: @RareFever yup used indexes